# How to create a function that should be called every time a button is clicked in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx

I created four components and the logic in App.js that will conditionally render each one of them. And I want to make a single button that would lead to the next component, but I don't know how to create it.

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import Etapa1 from "./components/Etapa1";
import Etapa2 from "./components/Etapa2";
import Etapa3 from "./components/Etapa3";
import Final from "./components/Final";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [etapa, setEtapa] = useState(1)

  const irParaProximaEtapa = () => {
    setEtapa.onClick(etapa + 1)
  }

  const renderizarEtapa = () => {
    switch (etapa) {
      case 1:
        return <Etapa1 />;
      case 2:
        return <Etapa2 />;
      case 3:
        return <Etapa3 />;
      case 4:
        return <Final />
      default:
      break;
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {renderizarEtapa}
      <button>Proxima etapa</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does the following help?: https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#examples-basic

Comment: Did you try: `<button onClick={nameOfTheFunctionToCall}>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line where you are passing a function inside the JSX is wrong:

```
{renderizarEtapa}
```

This will make React throw you a warning: "*Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.*"
Which should instead be called like:

```
{renderizarEtapa()}
```

Then, your `irParaProximaEtapa` is an *event handler function* and it shouldn't try to access properties of the setter function `setEtapa` because that's impossible, it should rather *call* the `setEtapa` function.

Next, to give your `button` element a *'click'* event listener you pass it an `onClick` prop with the event handler function modified to:

```
const irParaProximaEtapa = () => {
    setEtapa(etapa + 1)
  }
```

The final code would look like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import Etapa1 from "./components/Etapa1";
import Etapa2 from "./components/Etapa2";
import Etapa3 from "./components/Etapa3";
import Final from "./components/Final";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [etapa, setEtapa] = useState(1)

  const irParaProximaEtapa = () => {
    setEtapa(etapa + 1)
  }

  const renderizarEtapa = () => {
    switch (etapa) {
      case 1:
        return <Etapa1 />;
      case 2:
        return <Etapa2 />;
      case 3:
        return <Etapa3 />;
      case 4:
        return <Final />
      default:
      break;
  }
}

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {renderizarEtapa()}
      <button onClick={irParaProximaEtapa}>Proxima etapa</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```